# Using mixins (or eigenclasses, or some other methodology), is there a way to simulate the addition of a new superclass to Object?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, mixins

I'm aiming for a way to insert my own class (or module, as it may turn out) between `BasicObject` and `Object` in the hierarchy, so that all `Objects` now inherit from my class (or behave like my module). This is my testing set up:

```
module Entity
  # Define the singleton method Entity::new such that it generates and returns
  # a class which extends Entity.
  def self.new(*args, &blk)
    c = Class.new(*args, &blk)
    c.extend self
    c
  end

  # Singleton method
  def self.foo
    puts 'foo'
  end
  # Instance method
  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end
end
```

If I then create a class `Thing` which `include`s `Entity`, I get close to the output I desire:

```
thing = Thing.new
thing.bar #=> bar
Thing.foo #=> NoMethodError
```

Instances of `Thing` inherit the instance methods I defined in `Entity`, but the class `Thing` does not inherit the singleton methods of `Entity`, unfortunately.

If I attempt to add the `Entity` behavior to all objects via opening up the `Object` class and including `Entity`, not only do all objects inherit `Entity`'s instance methods, but they inherit them as singleton methods, too.

```
class Object; include Entity; end
Object.bar     #=> bar
Object.new.bar #=> bar

class Bob; end
Bob.bar        #=> bar
Bob.new.bar    #=> bar
```

This isn't what I want. I want all objects to inherit the behavior defined in `Entity` exactly as it is defined, so that instances of `Object` inherit `Entity`'s instance methods, and classes inheriting from `Object` inherit `Entity`'s singleton methods, just like standard inheritance. How can I modify what I've done to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal pattern for what you're describing would be to do something like this:

```
module MyModule
    def some_instance_method
    end

    module ClassMethods
        def some_class_method
        end
    end

    def self.included(othermod)
        class << othermod
            include ClassMethods
        end
    end
end
```

The included method will be called whenever the module is included in another class, and then the methods inside ClassMethods will be included in the classes metaclass

Comment: Thanks! I shall give this a try.

Comment: I've tried this, but it allows both the class `Bob` and instances of `Bob` to have access to `some_instance_method`:
`Bob.some_instance_method      #=> nil`
`Bob.new.some_instance_method  #=> nil`

Comment: sorry about the formatting of my comment, i can't figure out how to to blocks of code in comments

Comment: could you show us your new code? Its hard to say what might be wrong otherwise

Comment: Sure, I've posted it as a new question because...well because now it's a new question haha. [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687200/mixing-in-a-module-within-object-causes-all-objects-to-inherit-that-modules-ins)

Answer (score 1):

The established way (especially among Rails people) is to define the singleton methods as instance methods of some module, and use the `included` hook to `extend` the class with them.

```
module Entity
  def my_instance_method; ... end
  def self.included base; base.extend(ClassMethods) end
  module ClassMethods
    def my_class_method; ... end
  end
end
```

This is almost the same as Doydle's answer, but a little different.

Comment: If my understanding of `extend` is correct, isn't it just shorthand for exactly what Doydle does? Is that what you meant by 'a little different', or does it actually behave a little differently?

Comment: Using this method seems to result in the same behavior as Doydle's suggestion. This behavior is almost what I want, except I don't want classes that inherit from `Object` to inherit `my_instance_method` as an eigenmethod. As it is, the behavior definitely prevents instance methods defined within `ClassMethods` from being inherited as instance methods, which is a good thing.

Comment: `<< SomeClass` creates an eigenclass.

Comment: So does the `extend` method, according to this [article](http://erniemiller.org/2012/11/29/ruby-tidbit-include-vs-extend-with-module-class-variables/)

Comment: Unless `Baz.singleton_class.send :include, Foo` doesn't create the singleton class?