# Mixing in a module within Object causes all Objects to inherit that module's instance methods as singleton methods

Tags: ruby, include, extend, mixins, monkeypatching

When attempting to add my own behavior to the `Object` class, I get undesired effects that don't occur when mixing the module into a user-defined class.

```
module Entity
  def some_instance_method
    puts 'foo'
  end

  def self.secret_class_method
    puts 'secret'
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def some_class_method
      puts 'bar'
    end
  end

  def self.included( other_mod )
    other_mod.extend( ClassMethods )
  end
end
```

Now, I create class `Bob` such that it includes `Entity`.

```
class Bob; include Entity; end;
```

This yields the desired and expected output:

```
Bob.secret_class_method       #=> NoMethodError
Bob.some_instance_method      #=> NoMethodError
Bob.some_class_method         #=> bar
Bob.new.secret_class_method   #=> NoMethodError
Bob.new.some_instance_method  #=> foo
Bob.new.some_class_method     #=> NoMethodError
```

But if instead of defining class `Bob` I were to open up class `Object` and include `Entity` like so:

```
class Object; include Entity; end
```

Then the output I see is this:

```
Object.secret_class_method        #=> NoMethodError
Object.some_instance_method       #=> foo
Object.some_class_method          #=> bar
Object.new.secret_class_method    #=> NoMethodError
Object.new.some_instance_method   #=> foo
Object.new.some_class_method      #=> NoMethodError
```

If I then define class `Bob`, it behaves in the same way: `some_instance_method` can be called on class `Bob`. It seems as though something about the `Object` class itself is messing with the behavior of this pattern, or else I'm just doing something wrong here. Can someone please explain this odd behavior? I don't want all my `Object`s to inherit instance methods as singleton methods as well!

Answer (score 1):

`Bob` ia an object (more precisely: `Bob` is an instance of `Class`, which is a subclass of `Module` which is a subclass of `Object`, which is a subclass of `Entity`), therefore it has `Entity`'s methods. That's just how inheritance works.

Comment: Ahhh this makes sense *nod*. I've yet to fully wrap my head around the idea of class `Class` and what that means for the inheritance hierarchy of Ruby. Thanks for the clarification, sir.